# Multiple midi programs playing simultaneously?

Tags: python, midi, synthesizer, mido

I am using the mido library to control amsynth with python.

So far this is working beautifully...but I can only play one "preset" at a time however.

I'm trying to use "program_change" to switch instruments so I can play several instruments at once.

As a quick example:

```
import mido
from mido import Message
import time

outport = mido.open_output('amsynth:MIDI IN')

msg = Message('note_on', note = 64)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(2.0)

msg = Message('program_change', program = 1)
outport.send(msg)

msg = Message('note_on', note = 68) 
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(2.0)

msg = Message('note_off', note = 64)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(0.5)

msg = Message('note_off', note = 68) 
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

But when I try this, the note from the first program is cut as soon as I switch channels.

So maybe the issue is each program needs to be on a different channel:

```
import mido
from mido import Message
import time

outport = mido.open_output('amsynth:MIDI IN')

msg = Message('note_on', note = 64, channel = 0)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(2.0)

msg = Message('program_change', program = 1)
outport.send(msg)

msg = Message('note_on', note = 68, channel = 1)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(2.0)

msg = Message('note_off', note = 64)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(0.5)

msg = Message('note_off', note = 68)
outport.send(msg)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

But this doesn't work either.

As a workaround, I have been considering running multiple instances of amsynth...but that just seems perverse to me.

How can I play several instruments at once?

Edit:

It sounds like I will need to assign programs to channels before starting playback, and then play back per channel like so:

```
  msg = Message('program_change', program = 23, channel = 1)
  outport.send(msg)

  msg = Message('program_change', program = 3, channel = 2)
  outport.send(msg)

  msg = Message('note_on', note = 64, channel = 1)
  outport.send(msg)
  time.sleep(2.0)

  msg = Message('note_on', note = 68, channel = 2)
  outport.send(msg)
  time.sleep(2.0)

  msg = Message('note_off', note = 64, channel = 1)
  outport.send(msg)
  time.sleep(0.5)

  msg = Message('note_off', note = 68, channel = 2) 
  outport.send(msg)
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, this plays back both notes with program 3, so this doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: AmSynth is not multi-timbral, so there's no way to do what you're trying with a single instance of it.

Comment: Could it be that the synthesizer was monophonic or set in monophonic mode?

Answer (score 1):

With MIDI, there are 16 channels.  Each channel can be on one program/patch at a given time.  When you call `program_change`, you're changing the patch for that default channel.  You should send `program_change` for another channel, and then send MIDI notes to that other channel as well.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this (please see my edit) however this does not work. Did I do something incorrectly perhaps?